# Scrollviewer not showing scrollbars with negative margins

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I'm trying to add scrolling functionality to my application.  Basically using a mouse wheel you can scroll up and down, or if you hold Shift you can scroll left and right.

I created a little sample app to demonstrate the problem I'm having.

I'm using a ScrollViewer, that contains Canvas.  I place a Rectangle on the canvas, to represent a document Control I will be using in an actual application.
[image]

Everything works fine, when I try to scroll up using the mouse wheel.  The vertical scroll bar appears just fine, so user can return to previous positing by dragging it:
[image]

The problem is when I try ty scroll down instead.  The vertical scrollbar does not appear, so the only way to get back to previous position is by using the mouse wheel.
[image]

The same problem can be observed when scrolling in horizontal direction (by holding Shift).  It seems that scrollviewer knows when its content exceeds margins in positive direction, but is unaware of when the content goes in negative direction.

I've thought of a few workarounds (increasing size of canvas whenever user scrolls down for example), but I feel there has to be a better solution, and I'm just missing something.

Here's the code:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Scrolling Test" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="_scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Black">
            <Canvas Name="_canvas" Background="Gray" Width="400" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="150" Height="200" Fill="White"/>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace ScrollingTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _scrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(_scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel);
        }

        void _scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0)
                    ScrollLeft();
                else
                    ScrollRight();
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0)
                    ScrollUp();
                else
                    ScrollDown();
            }
        }

        void ScrollLeft()
        {
            Thickness newMargin = _canvas.Margin;
            newMargin.Left += 10;
            _canvas.Margin = newMargin;
        }

        void ScrollRight()
        {
            Thickness newMargin = _canvas.Margin;
            newMargin.Left -= 10;
            _canvas.Margin = newMargin;
        }

        void ScrollUp()
        {
            Thickness newMargin = _canvas.Margin;
            newMargin.Top += 10;
            _canvas.Margin = newMargin;            
        }

        void ScrollDown()
        {
            Thickness newMargin = _canvas.Margin;
            newMargin.Top -= 10;
            _canvas.Margin = newMargin;       
        }
    }
}
```

You can download the sample application (written using Visual Studio 2010) here:
http://www.filedropper.com/scrollingtest

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for now, I ended up replacing the scrollview control with a regular grid, and adding my own ScrollBar controls (vertical and horizontal).  This allowed me to customize their behavior to my requirements.